# Mysql server won't work when using another data directory

Tags: mysql, amazon-linux

I have an amazon ec2 instance running on Amazon Linux AMI. I'm trying to move the data directory for mysql on a second volume (mounted on `/home/ec2-user/data`) with following config file (`/etc/my.cnf`) but mysql fails to start:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/home/ec2-user/data/mysql
socket=/home/ec2-user/data/mysql/mysql.sock
log-bin=/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log-bin-index=/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[client]
port=3306
socket=/home/ec2-user/data/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I get these error messages in the log file:

```
2017-10-12 14:06:33 20082 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2017-10-12 14:06:33 20082 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
2017-10-12 14:06:33 20082 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /home/ec2-user/data/mysql/mysql.sock ?
2017-10-12 14:06:33 20082 [ERROR] Aborting
```

When I set the config file back to former settings (to the backup of the data folder) everything works fine:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql.bak
socket=/var/lib/mysql.bak/mysql.sock

log-bin=/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log-bin-index=/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[client]
port=3306
socket=/var/lib/mysql.bak/mysql.sock
```

What could be the cause of this problem? I've already checked for the permissions on the new data folder but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: can you post the result of ps ax | grep mysql ?

Comment: Hi farbiondriven, the only output i get is when running `ps ax | grep mysql`is `25418 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysql`

Comment: can you send ls -la /home/ec2-user/data/mysql/mysql.sock and ls -la /var/lib/mysql.bak/mysql.sock ? maybe the process cannot access the new file.

Comment: Both commands give the same output `ls: cannot access ...: No such file or directory`. When I start mysql with the old config I get this on the ls command for the old socket file: `srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Oct 12 15:17 /var/lib/mysql.bak/mysql.sock`

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
chgrp -R mysql /home/ec2-user/data/mysql
chown -R mysql /home/ec2-user/data/mysql
```

Can you try the following config file ?

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/home/ec2-user/data/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql.bak/mysql.sock

log-bin=/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log-bin-index=/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[client]
port=3306
socket=/var/lib/mysql.bak/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Mysql won't start but in the logs the socket is created and then I get a new error `[ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'user' is read only`

Comment: did you assign the ownership and the rights to the user running mysql on the folder /home/ec2-user/data/mysql ?

Comment: I've set this rights for the folder: `drwxr-xr-x 5 mysql    mysql     4096 Oct 12 15:29 mysql` (the same right of /var/lib/mysql.bak)

Comment: run this: chown -R mysql /home/ec2-user/data/mysql and then chgrp -R mysql /home/ec2-user/data/mysql

Comment: the chgrp and chown doesn't change the error. I'm not sure if this would be helpful but I've used this command to copy the old data directory to the new one: `sudo rsync -av /var/lib/mysql /home/ec2-user/data`